# How to implement voiceover/Talkback accessibility in react-native webview?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, webview, react-native-webview

I need to implement an accessibility feature of Voiceover(ios) or talkback(android) in React-native webview for both android and ios.

I am facing two issues:

**1**: I have div's and paragraphs (p tag) whose content has been read out by device. But I need to add some string as prefix or postfix in those.

**Example**

code is:  <*div> Hey Tap me to see magic <*/div>

Spoken content needed: 1 element of list "Hey Tap me to see magic" click to perform xyz action

.

**2**: Whenever action happen (i.e. on double tap of element) Device should speak:
"Magic has happened"

**What I have tried**

I have tried using speechSynthesis of HTML% Text to Speech:
var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('Hello World');
window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);

This approach is working for my **2nd issue** in ios (iphone X),
But No response in android devices

Thanks

Comment: If you control the content of the HTML, you might use `aria-label`.